# DeadObjectException with com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, google-api

I'm getting a frequent crash with the log below. It doesn't reference my application code but I'm guessing it may have something to do with GoogleApiClient connecting/disconnecting. Anyone get anything similar to this? I haven't been able to find anything on here.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ao.removeAllListeners(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ap.disconnect(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.n(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.a(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$2.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.r.y(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.q$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.an$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
  ... 15 more
```

Possibly where it's happening. I added a try/catch to catch the exception

```
mGApiClientMgr.addTask(mGApiClientMgr.new GoogleApiClientTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Refreshing data set.");
                Location location;
                try {
                    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(getGoogleApiClient());
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // TODO
                }
            }
        });
```

where `addTask` does:

```
  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<GoogleApiClientTask> mTaskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue
        <GoogleApiClientTask>();

  mTaskQueue.offer(task);
```

Comment: can you show code snippet of your gms listeners

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288685/deadobjectexception-in-gmslocationclient-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems related to handlers and message passing...Based on below snippet from your stack trace, `gms` is seeing a [`DeadObjectException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html) when trying to [process a `message`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) on the looper.  Even though the stack trace shows `gms` related, it could have be triggered by your code.

```
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.q$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

This exception is seen if the `message` its trying to access belong to a process that has since exited/killed. Do a code search for all [handler `sendMessage*` message dispatch calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), through out your code. Even this may not catch all instances as some `gms` calls could result in `handler` message dispatches.

Also, check if any of your background services, or activities that allocated `handler` messages, are exiting. Android could be destroying them [depending on life cycle states, try overriding `onDestroy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826670/deadobjectexception-on-android-app/21930743#21930743).

In all your activities/services, any where you make calls to `gms` api, check the objects you create and pass to `gms`; If they die, those objects are not valid any more.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Assuming the `sendMessage` is causing it, can I just wrap each of them with a try-catch to catch the IllegalStateException?

Comment: that wont help as `sendMessage` is just going to hand over the object to Message queue and return. The exception is happen at much later time, when `gms` pulls the object from Message queue. Mean while, the sender may have exited or killed by android life cycle. make sure you allocate object on a higher scope or see if you can retain.

Comment: A potential solution is to detect what Activity has been destroyed that is related to the object passed between the Activity and the Service via a Handler. Or identify the Service that is causing it and stop the service when the Activity is destroyed. Is this the way to go about it?

Comment: @ono yep, certainly helps if you can put in checks to detect leaks and handle them