# DeadObjectException with stacktrace pointing to : android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInstaller

Tags: android

I'm seeing in crash being reported in crashlytics which has this stack trace which has no mention of my app code.

I have seen [DeadObjectException with com.google.android.gms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104089/deadobjectexception-with-com-google-android-gms) and there, the crash was triggered when removing listeners.

Also, everytime my app starts, I get the installer for logging purposes, i.e.

```
packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(my-package-name)
```

There is no callback associated with this call.

Crash is observed mainly on Lollipop and Kitkat, though few Marshmallow and Nougat users have experienced it too.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInstaller(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1632)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source:8000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzc(Unknown Source:24000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpp.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
       at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInstaller(IPackageManager.java:4229)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInstaller(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1629)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source:8000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzc(Unknown Source:24000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpp.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Hi @Techeretic - did you ever find a solution to this? We are experiencing this same crash.

Comment: Hi @jyanks - I have copied over your code, so do let me know if you ever find a solution, it'll fix my app too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Fabric crashlytics reason for this exception.

DeadObjectExceptions are usually a symptom of a problem occurring somewhere else (likely in a remote process). Even though this exception may be safe to catch, it's worth looking for problems in related services.

---

This error could mean one of two things:

```
1) There is a bug (which caused a crash) in an associated process.

2) The other process was killed by the OS.
```

Source: Fabric crashlytics report.

Resources: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x/1574355#1574355) & [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314587/2556660)