# android DeadObjectException -- getting this on pause and resume. Using Google GMS

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am aware about the generic explanation of DeadObjectException  and I have gone through all the related links.

I am literally out of my mind, facing this. Can anyone please help.
First of all, I am not using any services, code is very simple and I am able to reproduce is every-time.

I have a activity A hosting a fragment and in that fragment I am using google location services to just display a Toast, as and when the location changes. (all other heavy code , I have commented)Sounds Simple, right!!!

Now I simply do a stress test...as soon as the app loads, I pause it and resume it...I do it 7-8 times real quick and this exception comes.

**Note:--** I have really done try catch(Exception e) everywhere --- in pause, in resume(in both activity and fragment), Also on create, onlocationchanged everywhere, but no where its get caught, so not even able to narrow down further.

Atleast I want to catch it.... Please help...
Anyone with similar experience. Its consistent on my Nexus 5
Here is the logcat:---

```
08-20 20:41:21.652    725-28451/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception thrown during pause
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
            at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:704)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:825)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2726)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2583)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2497)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11505)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11402)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12086)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11597)
            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
08-20 20:41:22.977    4255-4255/? E/BroadcastReceiver﹕ BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
    java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
            at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:445)
            at android.content.BroadcastReceiver$PendingResult.setResultCode(BroadcastReceiver.java:267)
            at com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver.onReceive(GCMPushReceiver.java:55)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24288685/1234913) is closest to my problem, but in my case, it comes while pause or resume.... not as illigalStateException

Here goes the code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Log.d("Nixxx", " oncreate Main called ");
            setContentView(R.layout.root_layout);
            tvToastMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_toast);
            pageId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(PAGE_ID);
            selectedLang = ApplicationSettings.getSelectedLanguage(this);


            AppDb dbInstance = new AppDb(this);
            dbInstance.open();
            currentPage = dbInstance.retrievePage(pageId, selectedLang);
            dbInstance.close();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                if ("location".equals(currentPage.getType())) {
                    tvToastMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    fragmentTag = "simpleLocation";
                    fragment = new SimpleLocationFragment().newInstance(pageId);
                } else {
                        fragmentTag = "simple";
                        fragment = new SimpleFragment().newInstance(pageId);
                    }
                }
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else {
                fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Nixxx------------"," I want to catch DOE");
        }
    }
```

The fragment--onActiviyCreated--

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    String pageId = getArguments().getString(PAGE_ID);
    String selectedLang = ApplicationSettings.getSelectedLanguage(getActivity());
    AppDB dbInstance = new AppDB(getActivity());
    dbInstance.open();
    currentPage = dbInstance.retrievePage(pageId, selectedLang);
    dbInstance.close();

```
if (currentPage.getStatus() == null || currentPage.getStatus().size() == 0) {
    llStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    String color = currentPage.getStatus().get(0).getColor();
    if (color.equals("red"))
        tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    else
        tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    tvStatus.setText(currentPage.getStatus().get(0).getTitle());
}

tvTitle.setText(currentPage.getTitle());
tvIntro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
lvActions.setAdapter(pageActionAdapter);
if (currentPage.getContent() == null)
    tv_contents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else {
    tv_contents.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPage.getContent(), null, new MyTagHandler()));
    tv_contents.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}try {
    locationInfo = LocationInfo.newInstance(getActivity());
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Nixxxy", "is there a DOE ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Nixxx------------"," Lets see onActivityCreated  locationFragment");
}
```

}

and in onPauseof the fragment, I call stopLocationUpdates and onResume startLocationUpdates();

and this id onLocationChanged:--

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        currentLocation = location;
        if (currentLocation != null)
            ApplicationSettings.setCurrentLocation(mContext, currentLocation);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Nixxx ","can i pleases see DOE on onLocationChanged");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is showing everything correctly ...except during stress testing it fails....

One more thing, if I comment out location related code, its ok, so I somehow feel related to GMS but why I am not able to catch...

startLocationUpdates, I am calling from onConnected

```
 public void startLocationUpdates() {

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d("Nixxxy", "startLocationUpdates started ");
            try {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Nixxx", "some DOE exception in startLocationUpdates");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let us see some code, cant help on blind...

Comment: @OfekRon Added the related code, can you see something now!!!!